# Reshape data frame by collapsing and creating new columns with Python

Tags: python, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
data = {'case_id': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
'file_name': ['512.mirnas', '512.isoforms', '360.isoforms', '478.mirnas', '360.mirnas', '478.isoforms']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['case_id', 'file_name'])
```

```
  case_id     file_name
0     aaa    512.mirnas
1     aaa  512.isoforms
2     bbb  360.isoforms
3     ccc    478.mirnas
4     bbb    360.mirnas
5     ccc  478.isoforms
```

For each unique "case_id", there are two "file_names", one mirnas and one isoforms. I want to collapse the "case_id" and create new columns for mirnas and isoforms file name. I'm trying to achieve this:

```
  case_id file_name_mirnas file_name_isoforms
0     aaa       512.mirnas       512.isoforms
1     bbb       360.mirnas       360.isoforms
2     ccc       478.mirnas       478.isoforms
```

I'm quite new to Python and I'm finding it difficult to get this done. I tried at df.pivot but it didn't work. I got the following error:
`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

I was thinking maybe I could create two new empty columns "file_name_mirnas" and "file_name_isoforms", then use groupby to fill these columns. But I am not very sure how to do it.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by separating them into different dataframes, and then joining them together:

I also noticed that some values are called "mirna" instead of "mirnas". I changed this for my answer.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'case_id': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
'file_name': ['512.mirnas', '512.isoforms', '360.isoforms', '478.mirnas', '360.mirnas', '478.isoforms']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['case_id', 'file_name'])

df_mirnas = df[df["file_name"].str.endswith("mirnas")]  # Grabs all that end with mirnas
df_mirnas.rename(columns={"file_name": "file_name_mirnas"}, inplace=True)  # Rename for join
df_iso = df[df["file_name"].str.endswith("isoforms")]  # Grabs all that ends with isoforms
df_iso.rename(columns={"file_name": "file_name_isoforms"}, inplace=True)  # rename for join

df_new = df_mirnas.join(df_iso.set_index("case_id"), on="case_id") # Joins them on case_id
df_new
```

```
>> 
case_id file_name_mirnas    file_name_isoforms
0   aaa 512.mirnas  512.isoforms
3   ccc 478.mirnas  478.isoforms
4   bbb 360.mirnas  360.isoforms
```

PS, I think groupby is super unintuitive to use, so don't feel bad about not always using it (even if it is probably more efficient, like here)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the queries in the pandas then you can do it this way.
1- separate the rows
2- selecting the two filenames for each case
3- making a new dataframe

```
from numpy.lib.arraysetops import unique
import pandas as pd

data = {'case_id': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'file_name': ['512.mirnas', '512.isoforms', '360.isoforms', '478.mirnas', '360.mirnas', '478.isoforms']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['case_id', 'file_name'])

print(df)

unique_caseid = sorted(set(df.loc[:, 'case_id']))
mirnas = []
isoforms = []
for id in unique_caseid:
    # first file name
    temp_index = list(df.loc[:, 'case_id']).index(id)
    file_name = df.loc[temp_index, 'file_name']
    if 'mirnas' in file_name:
        mirnas.append(file_name)
    else:
        isoforms.append(file_name)
    # 2nd file name
    ntemp_index = list(df.loc[:, 'case_id'])[temp_index+1:].index(id)
    temp_index += ntemp_index+1
    file_name = df.loc[temp_index, 'file_name']
    if 'mirnas' in file_name:
        mirnas.append(file_name)
    else:
        isoforms.append(file_name)

data = {}
data['case_id'] = unique_caseid
data['file_name_mirnas'] = mirnas
data['file_name_iosforms'] = isoforms

newdf = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=['case_id', 'file_name_mirnas', 'file_name_iosforms'])
print(newdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary column to hold `mirnas` and `isoforms`, then use the [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function to reshape your data, before finally collapsing the columns with a list comprehension:

```
df = (df.assign(temp=df.file_name.str.split(".").str[-1])
        .pivot("case_id", "temp")
       )

# flatten columns
df.columns = ["_".join(entry) for entry in df]

df.reset_index()

   case_id  file_name_isoforms  file_name_mirnas
0   aaa     512.isoforms        512.mirnas
1   bbb     360.isoforms        360.mirnas
2   ccc     478.isoforms        478.mirnas
```